# react web worker using npm package in code sandbox

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, web-worker

- I am trying to implement react web workers in my app.
- so I did a research and found this package  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webworker.
- I will have a thousands of numbers from this I need to splice one number and then pass it to api.
- since there will be more data.
- I have decided to use web worker.
- but when I include the code web worker result I am not getting.
- can you tell me how to make the web worker to work in my sand box.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-async-actions-y5ho5

```or-tag-here
<DataList
        doFetch={store.getState().fetched}
        data={store.getState().data}
      />

      <MyComponent />


const MyComponent = () => (
  <WebWorker url="/worker.js">
    let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,

  19, 20, 21,
];
let result= [];

let plantsSearchData = numbers.map(search => {
 // console.log("numbers---->", search);
  if (search.length > 1) {
            result.push(search);
  }

   console.log("pushed numbers---->", result);

});




    const response = await axios.get( "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2"
    );
    {({ data, error, postMessage, updatedAt, lastPostAt }) => (
      <div>
        {data && (
          <div>
            <strong>Received some data:</strong>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
          </div>
        )}
        <button
          onClick={() => postMessage("hello")}
          disabled={updatedAt < lastPostAt}
        >
          {updatedAt < lastPostAt ? "Loading..." : "Go"}
        </button>
      </div>
    )}
  </WebWorker>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

import web-worker on your main.js file
and create an instance of webworker on your componentDidMount() lifecycle

use this link for more info [web workers on react](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/introduction-to-web-workers-with-react/)

Comment: hey is it possible to update in my codesandbox, so confusing